# PHP array_walk does nothing?

Tags: php, arrays, glob

I'd like to put each file name in $xsl_dir_path (absolute path) in select element. I've tried this:

```
$files = glob($xsl_dir_path . "/*.xsl");
array_walk($files, 'basename');
```

but it's not working at all, i can still see the full names of the files. **I know** i can apply `basename` when lopping through `$files` and build the *option* elements, but i'd like to do it before any html output.

Comment: `glob()` will always serve the full file paths. If you don't want that, you need to cut it off afterwards

Comment: @Pekka i know that, that's why i want to apply basename function to each element of glob array (in an elegant way - meaning i don't like to loop on $files and create a new array).

Comment: ah, I see. I think that is because `basename()` doesn't conform with the kind of callback that `array_walk()` needs - you would have to build a custom function that modifies the first argument directly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`array_walk` is useful when your callback function accepts a reference or when you use user-defined callback functions. In this case, the `basename` argument is not a reference.

What you want is [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$files = glob($xsl_dir_path . "/*.xsl");
$files = array_map('basename', $files);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `basename()` isn't supposed to change the value of the array cells, only to return the new values. You need to pass to `array_walk()` a function that actually changes the value of the cell. Based on [array_walk docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
function my_basename(&$item)
{
    $item = basaname($item);
}

$files = glob($xsl_dir_path . "/*.xsl");
array_walk($files, 'my_basename');
```

Comment: Works but looks pretty ugly. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function basename_for_walk (&$value, $key) {
    $value = basename($value);
}
$files = glob($xsl_dir_path . "/*.xsl");
array_walk($files, 'basename_for_walk');
```